# What are the reasons to use an interface in java?

Tags: java, android

I just took some java classes this summer and everything is going very well, but I am stuck in **Interface**. I know that interface *allows us to group up methods with a class like a file* but when do we really get to use it in real programming. I am just a bit confused. Examples with definition will be appreciated.

Comment: `Interface` can also be used in Application Programming Interface (API) too.

Answer (score 3):

> interface allows us to group up methods with a class like a file

An interface is a contract.  It lacks implementation, it lacks the how.  But it specifies the what.

The advantage of this is that it gives us the ability to swap in and out different implementations (or solutions) without having to cascade the change to all places that the interface is used.

For examples, take a look within the JDK library.  They supply a List interface, and several alternative implementations that offer different implementations that are better in different situations.  For example, LinkedList and ArrayList both implement List but they perform very differently.  Sometimes LinkedList is better than ArrayList, other times the reverse is true.

Answer (score 1):

> but when do we really get to use it in real programming.

For me the simplest and most best way I always used is the `callback pattern` in which it has been used in most cases in `Listener`

Here is a simple example of a `callback pattern`

```
interface CallBack {
    void methodToCallBack();
}

class CallBackImpl implements CallBack {
    public void methodToCallBack() {
        System.out.println("I've been called back");
    }
}

class Caller {

    public void register(CallBack callback) {
        callback.methodToCallBack();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Caller caller = new Caller();
        CallBack callBack = new CallBackImpl();
        caller.register(callBack);
    }
}
```

In a more specific way:

```
// Reverse geocoding may take a long time to return so we put it in AsyncTask.
public class ReverseGeocoderTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, List<Address>> {
    private static final String TAG = "ReverseGeocoder";

    private Geocoder mGeocoder;
    private float mLat;
    private float mLng;
    private Callback mCallback;
    public ReverseGeocoderTask(Geocoder geocoder, float[] latlng,
            Callback callback) {
        mGeocoder = geocoder;
        mLat = latlng[0];
        mLng = latlng[1];
        mCallback = callback;
    }
    @Override
    protected List<Address> doInBackground(Void... params) {
        List<Address> address = null;
        try {
            List<Address> address =
                    mGeocoder.getFromLocation(mLat, mLng, 1);

        } catch (Exception ex) {
           // ignore
        } 
        return address;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<Address> address) {
        if(address != null)
           mCallback.onComplete(address);
    }
}

// the interface
public interface Callback {
   public void onComplete(List<Address> address);
}

// example fragment

public class MyCallbackFragment extends Fragment implements Callback{

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

       setContentView(R.layout.fragment_layout);
       // params the geocoder, float[] latlng, and the class that implements Callback
       new ReverseGeocoderTask(new Geocoder(getActivity(), Locale.getDefault()) , latlng, this).execute(null,null,null);
   }
  ...

  @Override
  public void onComplete(List<Address> address){
         // now we can get the address not interupting the main thread 
         // and also let the Task call us back to retrieve the information
         // and use it.

         // you can then use the address to display it anywhere you want in your UI



  }
}
```

*I have used this kind of pattern for the geo location of a taxi/cab app, so that I wont deal with it in fetching it myself rather let it call me and send me what i need if not null*

but this not the only thing you should look at. There are more ways in which you can use it.

from the docs : 
**Interfaces in Java**

*In the Java programming language, an interface is a reference type, similar to a class, that can contain only constants, method signatures, default methods, static methods, and nested types. Method bodies exist only for default methods and static methods. Interfaces cannot be instantiated—they can only be implemented by classes or extended by other* interfaces.

further reading [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/createinterface.html)

Hope it gives you a little insight on `Interface`

Answer (score 0):

From my perspective, an Interface indicates an action to perform at some certain time.

For example, the `onKeyDown` interface is invoked when a hardware key is pressed down. Here "press down" is a specific time, then what should we do at that time? Just call `onKeyDown` and that's all !

And another advantage is that through interface we needn't know anything about what the real class instance is, it's sufficient that we know there's a method we can call on.